# python, default package (pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, package, pycharm

pyCharm 2017.3

I use the package 'pandas', and add the package in 'Settings'

When I create new project, there is no pandas package so I have to re-add(install?) the pandas package..

how can I set the pandas package as a default.

Answer (score 0):

Go on File->settings-> open your project and go on project interpreter. There select your Project interpreter (Python version) and apply. This should solve your problem. If you dont have pandas package in your in your interpreter, then you can add it from there.